# Mysql rounding special case with integer fractions

Tags: mysql

I want to round field from DB with 2 decimals (item prices)

But when the price is an integer fraction (e.g. 10.00) I'd like to have it returned without decimals (i.e. 10)

so far ROUND(price, 2); doesn't solve the requirements

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fformat) instead of ROUND.

Comment: `select format(10.00,2);` returns the same 10.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(case when right(format(val, 2), 3) = '.00' then format(val, 0)
      else format(val, 2)
 end)
```

This will add commas into large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a single method exists to achieve this, but you can try something like this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MOD(50.00, 50) = 0 THEN ROUND(50.00) ELSE ROUND(50.00,2) END;
```

The above statement returns 50

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MOD(50.10, 50) = 0 THEN ROUND(50.10) ELSE ROUND(50.10,2) END;
```

The above statement returns 50.10

You can modify the number with dynamic column name.